# How to stop accelerometer to receive update?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

I am using CoreMotion in my app to use Accelerometer. I'm doing fine but how can i stop my accelerometer to receive motion update?

Comment: how about adding some comment why you downvote me. That would be great.

Comment: You question is unclear. Many people excepting "What you tried so far?"

Comment: have you try with `stopDeviceMotionUpdates` method?

Comment: Never mind, got what I need though. Thank you for down voting me.

Comment: @Viruss I used `[motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];` like what @mani said and it works. btw thanks for an answer. gl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
CMMotionManager *motionManager = [CMMotionManager sharedInstance];
[motionManager 
     startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *data, NSError *error)
     {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                        ^{
                        NSLog(@"hello");
                            [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
                        });   

     }];
```

Or using notification,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(stopAccelerometer)
                                          name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification 
                                        object:nil];
```

Comment: Nice. I used `[motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];` to stop the accelerometer. Work like a charm. Thanks man.